# React Native Radio Button (radio-buttons-react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, radio-button, radio-group

I'm using react native radio-buttons-react-native package I need to reset the value of the radio button whenever my isFocused is false or when I navigate to any other page. I can't use any other package because it's restricted

How can I solve this issue??

`

```
            <RadioButtonRN
              data={[{ label: "Lead" }, { label: "Client" }]}
              selectedBtn={(e) => {
                setRadioValue(e.label);
                handleChange(e.label, "type", el.uniqueId, index);
              }}
              ref={radioBtnRef}
              style={{
                width: 70,
                height: 50,
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                marginTop: -15,
              }}
              box={false}
              circleSize={10}
              activeColor={fontStyle.PRIMARY_COLOR}
              deactiveColor={"#000000"}
              textColor={"#000000"}
              textStyle={{
                fontSize: 11,
                textAlign: "center",
                fontFamily: fontStyle.FONT_FAMILY,
                color: fontStyle.COLOR_BLACK,
                fontWeight: "normal",
                marginLeft: 10,
              }}
              initial={1}
            />
```

`

I'd use ref and try to recreate the obj whenever I navigate to other screen

```
  function clearData() {
    setRadioValue('');
   setTodayPlanData([
      {
        uniqueId: uuid.v4(),
        type: "",
        id: "",
        time: null,
        reason: "",
      },
    ]);
    clientRef.current[0].reset();
    reasonRef.current[0].reset();
  }
```

Comment: Is this functional component? Also, where are you getting isFocused from?

Comment: yes, getting isfocused from this lib  import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";